# Select rows in a table where column length betwwen two values using JPA and CriteriaBuilder

Tags: mysql, jpa, eclipselink

I have a database table where one of the columns contains a code (the datatype of this column is a varchar). rows where the code is between 1 and 99 are countries. codes that are between 0101 and 9999 are counties where the two first characters are the same as the above described contry codes.

Ex:

- Code: 01 Location: USA
- Code: 0101 Location Alabama
- Code: 0102 Location Alaska

First of all, what operator should be used to say select all countries?
select * from table where code is between 00 and 99; 
select * from table where char_length(code) <= 2;
any other suggestion ?

Im using JPA and CriteriaBuilder in my application. I have found how to solve the between statement but my guess is that the length option is the better of them two. is it possible to use CriteriaBuilder to build the second query or if someone gives a better suggestion to how to select this.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/criteria/CriteriaBuilder.html#length(javax.persistence.criteria.Expression)

Comment: Thanks for the tip! Looks like your on to something. Having trouble through finding any good example of how to use expression in an query. Do you or anyone else know please send a link

Answer (score -1):

You could use this SQL statement:

```
select * from table where code between '00' and '99' and CHAR_LENGTH(code) = 2;
```

Hope this help!
Best.

Comment: Dont see how this helps, you just combined the two examples that i gave. How would this option be the best? And how to write it as a jpa query using criteriabuilder?

Comment: You're right, this answer doesn't help. As I'm not familiar with jpa I can only suggest my personal opinion about SQL. You should split information in two different tables. The first will contain Countries data, the second one County data. Just store a reference in County data to Country data (i.e. country_id).  The select statement could be "SELECT countries.name country_name, counties.name county_name FROM countries, counties WHERE countries.id = counties.id_country ORDER BY 1,2". Split information in two differente tables would be very helpful when writing code. My personal opinion.